# How to call default behavior of prevented event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Well, i have such-like code that prevent "select all" action from keyboard:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
   // CTRL key
   if ( e.which == '17' || e.which == '224' ){
      window.isCtrlHold = true;
   }
   // A key
   // Prevent from select all from a page ( ctrl + a )
   if ( e.which == '65' && window.isCtrlHold ){
     e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Another script called from another place that escape preventing off preview code:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
   window.inSearch = true;
});
$(document).keydown(function(e){
   // A ( "ctrl + a" if focus within text input )
   if ( e.which == '65' && window.isCtrlHold && window.inSearch ){
     // some code that do defult action eg "e.doDefault();"
   }
});
```

In the end, i need to prevent "ctrl+a" (select all) while focus not within input[type=text] and allow to select all if focus within input.

Comment: I don't need solution within current situation. I just need to know is there an any way to call default behavior that was prevented before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an opposite function of preventDefault() in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688567/is-there-an-opposite-function-of-preventdefault-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're approaching this the wrong way, just update your first code to be like this

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
   // CTRL key
   if ( e.which == '17' || e.which == '224' ){
      var isCtrlHold = true; //(note 1)
   }
   // A key
   // Prevent from select all from a page ( ctrl + a )
   if ( e.which == '65' && isCtrlHold && window.inSearch){
     e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Notice the `&& window.inSearch`.

Now you can remove this block of your code

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
   // A ( "ctrl + a" if focus within text input )
   if ( e.which == '65' && window.isCtrlHold && ! window.inSearch ){
     // some code that do defult action eg "e.doDefault();"
   }
});
```

**Edit:** I've noticed more errors in your code

Note1: `isCtrlHold` shouldn't be global, because clicking Ctrl (without holding) will make it `true` for ever (life of the page). Try to tap control (no holding) and then try to type `a`.

Note2: you should also add something like this:

```
$('input').blur(function(){
   window.inSearch = false;
});
```

or else your script will always think that the serachbox is in focus even though it isn't.

Note3: There's no "opposite" of `preventDefault();`, you either prevent default behavior or you don't.

Comment: Thank you, but problem in that i need to attach second script only if searchbox is exist on current page. And i can't know if it exist on current page. So i need some abstract behavior, that will extend default behavior of my script if searchbox attached to a current page.

Comment: @Ax., then just set `window.inSearch=false` in the beginning of your code. Now it will only be true if you there's a searchbox and the user is inside that searchbox.

Comment: :D that would be too simple way. Man, as i said, i can't edit default script behavior, so i need to extend default behavior if searchbox attached.

Comment: @Ax., according to what you explained in your question, this WILL solve your problem. Now, maybe your question isn't clear and you're missing some information, in that case it's your own fault. Nobody is gonna be able to read your mind and know your situation.

Comment: Man, you don't answer the question by itself. You trying to do some solution of current situation, but i don't need it. I just need to know is there an any way to call default behavior.

Comment: @ Note1, Note2 - i've missed this in this example only, as i said, i don't need solution, only knowledge.