# jQuery preventDefault() how to remove inside same click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery - How to remove click event preventDefault(), the code is like shown below,

```
$('button').on('click', 'loader', function(event){
    $.ajax({
          url: 'www.myweb.com/string/index.html',
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'html',
           success: function(data){ 
             event.preventDefault(); 
             // something else 
           },
            error: function(data){
             // how to remove event.preventDefault(); here?
           }
});
```

Comment: you can't do it like that because of the async nature of ajax

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for the answer, was googling but didn't find a good answer. then I will try to find another way to archive my goal.

Comment: With the nature of your [recent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851575/passible-to-pass-ajax-inside-variable-value-to-global) questions I would highly recommend reviewing [Ajax Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Most of your recent questions are covered there and it is invaluable when dealing with Ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the `$.ajax` function is asynchronous by default. Therefore, the success event handler would run after the click event handler has already returned.

If you really want to do this, you can specify the ajax call as synchronous, by setting the `async` option to `false`.

```
$('button').on('click', 'loader', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'www.myweb.com/string/index.html',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false
    }).done(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
    }).fail(function () {
        // Do something else here
    }));
```

Apparently you can't actually rollback `preventDefault`. [Once you call it, you cannot uncall it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688567/is-there-an-opposite-function-of-preventdefault-in-javascript) So it's important to only call the method in the `success` handler (or, in my modified example, the `done` method).

Comment: was going to recommend that very thing