# passible to pass $.ajax inside variable value to global?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to pass the test value from ajax function to global?

```
$('button').on('click', 'loader', function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: 'www.myweb.com/string/index.html',
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'html',
           success: function(data){ 
             var test = true;
           },
            error: function(data){
              var test = false;

           }
});

var test;
```

my console.log shows `undefined`

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.  (also, that's a _local_ variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

Inside your success handler, you are redefining `test` with the `var` keyword. This is now using a new variable named `test` that is scoped for just your success handler.

Remove the `var` keyword. Then it will look for a variable named `test` in the outer scope, searching progressively outward until it either finds a variable named `test`, or fails to find one in which case it will create a new variable attached to `window`.

Your second problem is that ajax is asynchronous by default. That means it would not be calling `test = true` until all of the subsequent code has finished running.  If you are examining the value of `test` immediately after the `ajax` call, then it will be `undefined` because the `done` hasn't been called yet.

For this simple example, make the call synchronous, by setting the `async` property to false.

```
// Do you want to use the text within this scope?
// If not, remove this declaration, and then it really will be
// window.test
var test;

$('button').on('click', 'loader', function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: 'www.myweb.com/string/index.html',
          type: 'get',
          async: false,
          dataType: 'html'
}).done(function() {
     test = true;
}).fail(function() {
    test = false;
});
```

Comment: no mention of `async` this time? Doing this in without it is probably worse then the use of `async`

Comment: @Matt Green: Actually, I believe this would use the `test` that is declared after the ajax method call, because, chronologically, the declaration will run before the `success` method is called. This is slightly confusing code, but not actually incorrect :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! @AndrewShepherd Copied twice for a reason? and still get `undefined`

Comment: @olo Actually, @Matt Green is correct, it should set `async` to false. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd actually, it doesn't matter where the variable declaration is placed, see [`var` hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Thanks, I didn't actually know that.

Comment: Thanks guys!! may need to think a better solution as `async: false`

Comment: @olo see if it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: @AndrewShepherd, I did not mean it was incorrect, but what if another function is called while the `Ajax` promise is still not resolved that expects `test` to have the "new" value. It could cause very unexpected behavior

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the `var` keyword inside the ajax callbacks when setting `test`'s value.

Comment: thanks, I've tried without `var` but still cant get the right value;